# how to get file name of multipart-form file in go?

Tags: go, multipart

I am trying to upload a multipart form which has a file along with some other data. I know the tag name for the file using which I do FormFile but I want to get the name of the file also. I am not able to figure out how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Given a simple form like this in a file called `form.html`:

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>File Upload example</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="/form-endpoint" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label for="file-input">Choose an image</label>
        <input type="file" id="file-input" name="file-input" accept="image/png, image/jpeg">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

I can get the file name of the uploaded file using the POST request's `*multipart.Reader` struct like so in a file called `main.go`:

```
package main

import (
    "io"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func serveForm(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    http.ServeFile(w, r, "form.html")
}

func handleFormSubmit(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    reader, err := r.MultipartReader()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to create multipart-reader: %s", err)
    }

    for p, err := reader.NextPart(); err != io.EOF; p, err = reader.NextPart() {
        log.Println(p.FileName())  // This line in particular is what you're looking for.
    }
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", serveForm)
    http.HandleFunc("/form-endpoint", handleFormSubmit)
    if err := http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nil); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to start server: %s", err)
    }
}
```

This is a good starting point in the docs to learn more about `multipart/form-data` reading: https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.MultipartReader

Answer (score 1):

`FormFile()` is a convenience function that will return the file for reading and its header, which contains the `Filename` and `Size` properties.

```golang
func handleFormSubmit(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    f, fHeader, err := r.FormFile("file-input")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    
    // get the filename and size in bytes
    fmt.Fprintln(w, fmt.Sprintf("Your file name is %q, and it is %d bytes", fHeader.Filename, fHeader.Size))

    // read the file's data
    data, err := io.ReadAll(f)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Fprintln(w, data)
}
```